# Order Subindex in dataframe and sum the top "n" entries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                    Population2010
State     County

AL        Baldwin     90332
          Douglas     92082
          Rolling     52000
CA        Orange      3879602
          San Diego   4364594
          Los Angeles 12123562
CO        Boulder     161818
          Denver      737728
          Jefferson   222368
AZ        Maricopa    2239378
          Pinal       448888
          Pima        1000564
```

I would like to put the data in descending order based on the population but also have it be ordered by the state

```
                    Population2010
State     County

AL        Douglas     92082
          Baldwin     90332
          Rolling     52000
CA        Los Angeles 12123562
          San Diego   4364594
          Orange      3879602
CO        Denver      737728
          Jefferson   222368
          Boulder     161818              
AZ        Maricopa    2239378
          Pima        1000564
          Pinal       448888
```

and then I would like to sum the first two entries of population data and give the two states with the highest sums.

```
'CA', 'AZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1:

```
df.sort_values(['Population2010'], ascending=False)\
  .reindex(sorted(df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()), level=0)
```

or

```
df.sort_values('Population2010', ascending=False)\
  .sort_index(level=0, ascending=[True])
```

Output:

```
                  Population2010
State County                     
AL    Douglas               92082
      Baldwin               90332
      Rolling               52000
AZ    Maricopa            2239378
      Pima                1000564
      Pinal                448888
CA    Los Angeles        12123562
      San Diego           4364594
      Orange              3879602
CO    Denver               737728
      Jefferson            222368
      Boulder              161818
```

First, sort the entire dataframe by values descending, then get the values from the index for level=0, sort them and use to reindex on level=0 to sort the dataframe in groups of level 0.

## Question 2 somewhat unrelated calculation to the first:

```
df.groupby('State')['Population2010']\
  .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(2).sum())\
  .nlargest(2).index.tolist()
```

Output:

```
['CA', 'AZ']
```

Use nlargest to find two largest values grouped by state and sum, then use nlargest again to find the two largest states for those sums.

Comment: @geojasm If this answer helped you, would you consider [upvoting and accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top)?